# PushNotification Phonegap in Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using this plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to send notifications to my users using my android app. Well, so far it's ok.

I have the following questions:
Every time the user opens my app I need to generate a new "RegID"? Or,is not necessary?

Because I'm saving the "RegID" in the database, for later make a shipping notification with PHP to the user's device.
What if every time open the app necessary generate a new "RegID" need to update my database alright?

Somebody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to generate a new Registration ID in each launch of your app. You should only generate it the first time your app is launched (and it's also recommended by Google to generate it again when a new version of your app is installed).

Even when you request Google for a new Registration ID, you might get in response the same registration ID you already had, in which case make sure you don't duplicate that Registration ID in your DB.

Comment: Thank you for answer and another question. 
At the moment there is a new version of the application how can I make this check and generate a new "RegID"?

Comment: @RoniSommerfeld You're welcome! As for the other question, check the [official demo](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java) to see how this is handled. The idea is to store the current RegID and app version in SharedPreferences, and to check whether the version has changed each time the app is launched.